# Git: commit before merge?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-commit

I was advised to commit all my changes before running `git pull` and merge. Does it make sense ? What if I run `pull` and `merge` *before* committing my changes and commit them *after* the merge?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Committing before pulling is **not** always advisable -- you should consider stashing your work instead.

A better way to think about this is in terms of your staging area. Ideally, you'd like it to be clean before you attempt to merge in remote changes (remember, `git pull` = `git fetch` + `git merge`).

`git commit` is *one* way of accomplishing this, but it will alter your history--thereby polluting it if you're concerned about leaving your repo in a constantly working state.

`git stash`, on the other hand, was built for use cases just like this.

> Use git stash when you want to record the current state of the working directory and the index, but want to go back to a clean working directory.

source: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash

You workflow would then look something like this:

```
$ git stash
$ git pull origin master
$ git stash pop stash@{0}
```

This will allow the pull to execute without issues, vocally warn you when applying your stash has resulted in conflicts.

Comment: Most useful answer so far. You should probably suggest calling `git stash` with `--all` or `--include-untracked` to avoid risking the merge operation failing with "untracked files would be overwritten by merge".

Comment: One caveat with stashing is that it doesn't create an entry in the reflog—so, if you screw up and lose your stash, you can't recover it.  In some ways a commit is "safer."  You can also `git pull --rebase` after a commit rather than stashing.

Answer (score 3):

Uncommitted changes are always bad:

- Either your changes are good, then commit them
- or they are bad, then discard them.

Uncommitted changes are completely unknown to git. Therefore git cannot help you in any way if anything goes wrong and you risk loosing you work in case of problems.

You avoid many problems if you simply make sure you don't have any uncommitted changes whenever you are doing any git operation like the pull in your case.

Comment: What about unfinished changes? They aren't good enough to be committed, but not bad and should be discarded... For example, I would like to merge some code from origin that would be helpful while finishing these new changes.

Comment: There is also the TBD state :)

Answer (score 1):

If you try to merge changes on files that have modifications, `git` will just refuse to do it. That is why committing first is a good idea. If you don't do it in that order, it will either merge fine (if the files you changed were not involved in any other commits that are being merged), or nothing will happen, and `git` will tell you that your merge can't be done.

Answer (score 1):

If you do a commit before you pull you can go back to that point if something goes wrong with the pull/merge. You don't have to do it, just good practice.